# Why is selecting values from a large hash based on a large array so slow?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with approximately 150k elements, and an array with 25k elements. I need to create a new hash, or modify the existing one, to remove all elements whose key is not on the array. Here is what I have now:

```
hash.select {|k,v| array.include?(k)}
new_hash = hash.delete_if {|k,v| !array.include?(k)}
```

The two methods are extremely slow because of the comparison complexity. Is there is a way it can be sped up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(hash.keys - array).each{|k| hash.delete(k)}
```

Or, this might be even faster:

```
keys_to_be_removed = {}
hash.each{|k, _| keys_to_be_removed[k] = true}
array.each{|k| keys_to_be_removed[k] = false}
keys_to_be_removed.each{|k, v| hash.delete(k) if v}
```

The point is to avoid array operations and do everything in hash as much as possible.

Comment: I added another one. Please try it too.

Comment: @sawa: I added your second version to my [microbenchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15774706/1074296).  It's certainly not an improvement :(

Answer (score 2):

@sawa's answer is fine at getting good speed, but it does make you express your intent a little more awkwardly than `Hash#select`.  Your initial approach would work just fine if the array was a [`Set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) with O(1) lookup instead of an array with O(N) lookup.

```
require 'set'

set = array.to_set
hash.select { |k,v| set.include?(k) }
```

[This microbenchmark](https://gist.github.com/dbenhur/5296334) demonstrates sets are fast and this approach is marginally faster than the key-subtraction-delete method @sawa recommended when the set is pre-built and just marginally slower if the set must be made on the fly.

```
                          user     system      total        real
noop                    0.600000   0.020000   0.620000 (  0.614905)
keys_minus_arr_delete   1.190000   0.020000   1.210000 (  1.213376)
select_set_include      1.050000   0.010000   1.060000 (  1.084079)
select_set_include_fly  1.350000   0.020000   1.370000 (  1.361623)
sawa2                   1.860000   0.020000   1.880000 (  1.870162)
```

Comment: Really nice answer. I didn't know about the `Set` performance.